# How to process nodejs JSON in the BASH script?

Tags: json, bash

I am calling nodejs function from bash script which returns JSON output like below:

```
[ { fullyQualifiedDomainName: 'XXXXXXXX',
   hostname: 'XXXXXXXX',
   id: XXXXXXXXxxxx,
   primaryBackendIpAddress: 'XXXXXXXXxx',
   primaryIpAddress: 'XXXXXXXXxx' },
 { fullyQualifiedDomainName: 'XXXXXXXX',
   hostname: 'XXXXXXXX',
   id: XXXXXXXXxxxx,
   primaryBackendIpAddress: 'XXXXXXXXxx',
   primaryIpAddress: 'XXXXXXXXxx' },
{ fullyQualifiedDomainName: 'XXXXXXXX',
   hostname: 'XXXXXXXX',
   id: XXXXXXXXxxxx,
   primaryBackendIpAddress: 'XXXXXXXXxx',
   primaryIpAddress: 'XXXXXXXXxx' },
{ fullyQualifiedDomainName: 'XXXXXXXX',
   hostname: 'XXXXXXXX',
   id: XXXXXXXXxxxx,
   primaryBackendIpAddress: 'XXXXXXXXxx',
   primaryIpAddress: 'XXXXXXXXxx' }]
```

I want to retrieve all the ids from above output. Is there a way to do this? Output can have details for n number of devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is not JSON. This would be JSON:

```
[{ "fullyQualifiedDomainName": "XXXXXXXX",
   "hostname": "XXXXXXXX",
   "id": "XXXXXXXXxxxx1",
   "primaryBackendIpAddress": "XXXXXXXXxx",
   "primaryIpAddress": "XXXXXXXXxx" },
 { "fullyQualifiedDomainName": "XXXXXXXX",
   "hostname": "XXXXXXXX",
   "id": "XXXXXXXXxxxx2",
   "primaryBackendIpAddress": "XXXXXXXXxx",
   "primaryIpAddress": "XXXXXXXXxx" },
 { "fullyQualifiedDomainName": "XXXXXXXX",
   "hostname": "XXXXXXXX",
   "id": "XXXXXXXXxxxx3",
   "primaryBackendIpAddress": "XXXXXXXXxx",
   "primaryIpAddress": "XXXXXXXXxx" },
 { "fullyQualifiedDomainName": "XXXXXXXX",
   "hostname": "XXXXXXXX",
   "id": "XXXXXXXXxxxx4",
   "primaryBackendIpAddress": "XXXXXXXXxx",
   "primaryIpAddress": "XXXXXXXXxx" }]
```

And in this case `jq` is the first choice to query values form JSON data.

```
$ jq '.[].id' json
"XXXXXXXXxxxx1"
"XXXXXXXXxxxx2"
"XXXXXXXXxxxx3"
"XXXXXXXXxxxx4"
```

Or use the raw output to store the result in an Bash array:

```
$ ids=($(jq -r '.[].id' json))
$ printf "%s\n" "${ids[@]}"
XXXXXXXXxxxx1
XXXXXXXXxxxx2
XXXXXXXXxxxx3
XXXXXXXXxxxx4
```

Answer (score 1):

In your bash script , at loop take those id to an array then  give that command 
to run your Nodejs script with parameter

`node index.js -idArray [your id data like 1,2,3,4]`

Put this code to your Nodejs file to use your array

`let argv = require('minimist')(process.argv);
 console.dir(argv.idArray);`

Comment: how to get ids from this output in bash script?

Comment: If it's type is string you can string match in loop then push to  an array.Search some bash script string match if type is string or look some loop operations.I guess you can accept above code as answer